# Logstash - Setting a field to a value if first 2 characters of another field match a given string

Tags: logstash

I need to check if a field [environment] starts with two letters 'MX' and if so, add a field called [IsMX] with the value true.

Please can someone help me with how to do this in Logstash?

Comment: You'll need conditionals (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html#using-conditionals) and a regexp (test them at http://rubular.com/).  Post back with what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks for your links, Alain.  I'm going to try the following tomorrow and I'll post back if it works:`if [environment]=~ "/MX\w*/i" { add_field => {"IsMX" => "true"} }`   I added the `/i` to make the string match case-insensitive.  To be honest though, now I know I can use the =~ operator, I don't think I will need to add a field to my document; I will just use this straightforward regex check :-)

Comment: Not bad!  You said "starts with", so use "/^MX/".  add_field also has to be part of a filter, so you'd need: "mutate { add_field => { ... } }".

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you once again.